# generate XLS files using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, xls

I would like to generate XLS files using PL/SQL. This includes entring text into cells, coloring cells, bordering cells and merging cells.

This may include also:

- different fonts, sizes, styles, alignings and colors of text
- different line arrangement, styles and colors of borders
- different types (number, text, time, date, boolean, ..) of cells

Can please anyone direct me, where can I find any documentation, methods, examples.. - anything about how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from MS Office 2003 you can create XLS files as usual XML files. The official documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_xmlss_hierarchy) and some PL/SQL examples can be found [here](http://greatxam.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/xml-format-for-excel/) or [here](http://akdora.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/how-to-write-excel-via-plsql-and-save-the-file-to-a-directory/).

Everything you've stated in requirements can be done this way.

Hope this helps.

I've done a general XLS from PL/SQL reporting solutions using this techniques: there's hardly any difficult things. Feel free to ask if you have any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the work done by Jason Bennett on hist [PL/SQL ExcelDocumentType](http://www.jasonsdevelopercorner.com/?page_id=8)